# Console will not wait for file load before printing

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I have a file containing JSON data that I want to read.  I found some code for reading a file at neontribe.co.uk, but I can't seem to get the console to wait for the load to complete.

```
function onDeviceReady(){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(fs) {
var directoryReader = fs.createReader();
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
var i;
for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady2, false);  
function onDeviceReady2() {  
    function readFromFile(fileName) {
        var pathToFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + fileName;
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                console.log("Inside Load" + JSON.parse(this.result));
                    return JSON.parse(this.result);
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }


    function some_function(callback) {

    console.log("inside function1"); 
    var data = readFromFile(entries[i].name);

    callback(data);
}



some_function(function(data) {


    console.log("data!" + data);
    console.log("Data String!" +  JSON.stringify(data));

});


  //  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  // console.log("arresteeFirst!" + data.arresteeFirst);
   // console.log("data!" + data);
}
console.log(entries[i].name);
}


}, function (error) {
alert(error.code);
});
}, function (error) {
alert(error.code);
});
}
```

When I run it I get this output in the console:

inside function1
Data!undefined
Data String!undefined
1452034357845.json
Inside Load[object Object]

So it looks like it goes to some_function and then prints the inside function 1.  But then it does not wait for the function to pass the result from the load.  It prints the two lines from the callback function straight away.  It then prints the filename (at the end of the loop) and then finally prints the console message from within the load function.  It looks like I am returning an object according to the console so data should not be undefined.

Comment: [Promises!  Promises!](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few bits wrong with the code, mainly because it's not written taking into account the asynchronous calls and just assuming that everything happens in a synchronous fashion.

The `callback(data)` within `some_function(callback)` is in fact called after you called `var data = readFromFile(entries[i].name);`. But two issues arise here.

1. `function readFromFile(fileName)` doesn't return any data (actually, it doesn't return anything at all);
2. `reader.readAsText(file);` is treated asynchronous. In a nutshell, it means that your code will keep running (in your case print those messages) and call the `reader.onloadend` callback once the data is fully loaded - which would be too late for you as your message has already been printed.

There are several ways to fix this code, a good way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for promises personally.
With promises, the solution would look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
function readFromFile(fileName) {
   return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
       var pathToFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + fileName;
       window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
           fileEntry.file(function (file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    console.log("Share the results... " + JSON.parse(this.result));
                    resolve(JSON.parse(this.result));
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    } // Return the promise
}

function some_function(callback) {
    console.log("inside function1"); 
    var promise = readFromFile(entries[i].name);

    promise.then(callback); // Will be called when promise is resolved
}

some_function(console.log);
```

Promises allows you to conceptually return a "contract" that the value will be fetched and all functions waiting for that value (`.then`) will be called once the data is received and the promise is resolved (you can reject a promise if it fails as well). (Sorry about the bad explanation, but there are loads of better documentation about it all over the internet, I recommend taking a look at it).

I hope it helps, there are other ways of coming around this problem, I believe that a promises might be the most elegant without getting into generators.